# Why an object is removed after using removeAll method

Tags: java

I have executed a program. After removing an object from a list reflects another list.

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList<>();
        a1.add("a");
        a1.add("e");
        a1.add("f");
        ArrayList a2 = new ArrayList<>();
        a2.add("a");
        a2.add("x");
        a2.add("y");

        a1.removeAll(a2);
        Iterator<String> it = a1.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
```

And output I'm getting is:
e,f

Why is 'a' removed ?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: What do you think `removeAll` does? Why do you think `a` shouldn't be removed?

Comment: Did you expect `removeAll` to do nothing? If that's what you expected, why did you call it at all?

Comment: @Littlebird. Let's say you have 3 birds, [parrot,peacock,pigeon] and I have 3 birds [parrot,eagle,owl] and I tell you to kill all the birds that you have that are similar to the birds I have. Which bird will you kill? (Assuming that you have no way out except to kill a bird)

Comment: I want to know if if i'm adding 'a' in a1 and a2 both. While  deleting a2 list from a1 , deletes 'a' object ?

Comment: Please just read the documentation. [WHY CANT WE GET IT TO READ!?](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BxH3DZvCYAAl1ip.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you called `a1.removeAll(a2)` perhaps?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29

> Removes from this list all of its elements that are contained in the specified collection (optional operation).

So, in other words, every element that's in `a2` and also in `a1` will be removed from `a1`.

Comment: I agreed ... So it means a1 and a2 both are referencing to the same element 'a' ?

Comment: @LittleBird No they're not, you remove it from `a1` NOT from `a2`. Try iterating over `a2`, you'll see element 'a' is still in there.

Answer (score 0):

a1.removeAll is a method that can take another array. This is how you are using it. It can remove all occurrences of that other array from the current array. In your example, a1 has a value of ["a", "e", "f"] and a2  has a value of ["a", "x", "y"]. a1.removeAll(a2) will try to remove all of the values contained in a2 from a1. Since "a" is a value in a2, it is removed from a1.